# php global variables in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

So i have a page called user.php as test

```
<?php 
$user = $_GET['userID'];
echo $user;
?>
```

then i have .js that uses ajax to add a comment on the profile which works but the php that it uses (select and insert) is in a file called profileComments.php

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'profileComments.php',
        method: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: {
            display: 1,
            user: userID
        },
        success: function () {
            insertComments();
        }
    });
```

now i want to edit the select query of that profileComments.php file to only display those with the right userID

```
<?php
include "db.php";
$user = $_GET['userID'];

if (isset($_POST["display"])) {
  $comments= "SELECT * FROM comments";
  $query= mysqli_query($connection, $comments);

  while ($comments = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $comments["content"]?>
        </li>
    <?php }
}
```

But the problem is when I edit it in

```
"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE userID = $user"
```

at the top i've written this $user = $_GET['userID']; but it gives me the unidentified error

How can i make this work?

Comment: it's not clear to me which script gets included into the other one. And which one is called via ajax. Can you please clarify that in your question?

Comment: You should probably show the code that calls `profileComments.php`.  Also, there is no such thing as "an ajax file".  AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript, and is a technology.

Comment: Also read up on SQL Injection and "Little Bobby Tables"

Comment: Without knowing your ajax call code, it could be `$_POST['userID'];` ...

Comment: I updated the question with the ajax code and the profileComments

Comment: also in your success-callback you don't ever use the data which get's sent back from php. might be something like this: `success: function (html) {
            insertComments(html);
        }`

Comment: I tried to make a function with the get method but i just don't know how to fix this problem, like my URL is like this: /user.php?userid=1 and i don't know how to get the userid

Answer (score 1):

You're using AJAX to send a POST request, not a GET request (See the method value of your ajax request).  Therefore, all of the data in that AJAX request will be read into the `$_POST` superglobal of PHP.

You also named that key `'user'`, not `'userID'` (see the data value of your ajax request).

Try:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
```

Comment: I tried that but i still get the same error, just want to get the user from the URL and i thought $_GET would do that job but i'm new to this and yea still wondering how to make it work

Comment: You tried `$_POST['user']`? Because that matches your code.   If you want to put it in the URL, then put it in the URL.  You could set the AJAX url to `'profileComments.php?userID=' + userID`

Comment: i'm not following?

Comment: @anonymous It's very simple: POST data is put in `$_POST`, URL parameters are in `$_GET`.

Comment: So on comments I added $user = $_POST["user"]
and my Ajax now looks like this
$.ajax({
        url: 'profileComments.php?userID' + userID,
        method: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: {
            display: 1,
            user: userID
        },
        success: function () {
            insertComments();
        }
    });

This still results in the same error, so im not sure what I do wrong and I apologize that I'm asking a lot since im new to this

Comment: @anonymous what's the exact error?  You don't need to do both:  Add userID to the URL to access `$_GET['userID']` or include user in the POST data to access `$_POST['user']`.  Having userID included twice is redundant.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: userID in /path/to/directory/comment.php on line 3
and this is after putting $id = $_GET['id'] on the profileComments page and having            url: 'profileComments.php?userID=' + userID in the Ajax call

Comment: That's a different file than profileComments.php... Are you looking at the response of your ajax request for this error!?

Comment: yes sorry I mistyped the name of the page in my reply here, but yes I'm looking at the response and it keeps giving me the undefined index error

Comment: It has been fixed, I tried a workaround that I came up with to fix the issue, thanks for all the help it was a huge help to achieve this